# Displaying data from multiple entities in a single NSTableView (Core-Data)

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nstableview

I have an entity called Pupil, and an entity called Loan.
The Pupil entity has the attributes: firstName, lastName, address, postCode, telephoneNumber.
The Loan entity has the attribute: loanID,  and the relationship: pupilID, which is a relationship to the entity Pupil.

I wish to display the loanID, with the pupil (if any) related to the loanID in a table.
e.g.:

```
LoanID | firstName | lastName | address     | postCode | telephoneNumber
   1   |    bob    |  smith   | 98 Any Road |  N1 1QW  | 0123456789
```

How would I go about this? I am currently using the bindings for my other tables.

Thank you!

Comment: It may help to include a few more address-related fields in your table, since pupils may move to another city, state, or country. Or, go the other way, and let the user enter all of those things and the postal code as part of the address.

Comment: Yeah, I would normally do this, but for this particular program, all users have to be within a certain borough to become a member, once they leave, they can no longer be a member.
Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this assuming that you have set the reverse relationship for `pupilID` (i.e. a relationship from Pupil to the Loan). If you call that relationship `loan`, and have an `NSArrayController`, `PupilsController` bound to the collection of Pupils, then your first table could be bound to `PupilsController.arrangedObjects.loan.loadID` and your other columns bound as you'd expect.

On a purely stylistic side note, the `pupilID` property would more appropriately be named `pupil`. Core Data is no an ORM and you're not in SQL JOIN land any more. Name the properties what they are, not how they're implemented under the hood by Core Data.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will change the relationship names around too!